# How to reach DI context of REST Assured?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, rest-assured, quarkus

I am testing my (Quarkus) application with RESTAssure with the following example

```
ExtractableResponse<Response> extract = given()
                .when()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .body(request)
                .post(API_SUPPORTED_CHECK)
                .then()
                .statusCode(OK.getStatusCode())
                .extract();
```

apparently, it creates DI context somewhere in the memory and it is separate from the testing context. At least, if I inject some beand into test class with

```
@Inject
MyClass myBean;
```

and change it's properties, they don't change in beans inside tested application.

Is it possible to reach beans of tested application from test?

Comment: What context are you referring to?

Comment: @geoand where beans of web application are